# Spring MVC how to load a js from a jsp

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, jspinclude

I work with Spring MVC. I have a dynamic web project Eclipse

Structure folder is

[image]

I have the following jsp actualizarCorreo.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>EusurveyAdmin menu princiapl</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/properties.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function pruebaB()
{
   alert('en prueba');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <c:set var="pageNumber" value="${pageNumber}" />
    <table class="actualizarCorreos">

        <tbody>
        <a href="#" onclick="prueba()"; return false;">
            <input type="radio" onclick="prueba()" class="check" id="id1"
                name="id1" value="true" />
            <spring:message code="label.ModificarCorreos" />



        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
```

In this jsp I load another js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/properties.js">
```

This js is the path WebContent/resources/js.

properties.js is

```
alert('cargado properties');
function checkConfirmationPage()
{       
    alert('en check');
    if ($("#conflink").is(":checked"))
    {} else {};
}

function prueba()
{
    alert('en prueba');
}
```

I call function prueba from actualizarCorreo.jsp when a radio button is clicked

```
<input type="radio" onclick="prueba()" class="check" id="id1"
                name="id1" value="true" />
            <spring:message code="label.ModificarCorreos" />
```

I don't see the alert message function prueba.

What is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/js/properties.js"></script>
```

or use the below as reference and find the exact path:

```
   /   = Root directory
   .   = This location
   ..  = Up a directory
   ./  = Current directory
   ../ = Parent of current directory
   ../../ = Two directories backwards
```

Or directly get the context path to fetch the .js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/properties.js" >
</script>
```

Comment: I tried another paths and I get message error  <No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/EusurveyAdminB/correos/corregir/resources/js/properties.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'eusurveyadmin'> I think path are right

Comment: I have suggested another option. Please do try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

While using Spring framework in mvc you have to provide resources path as below in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

```
< mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

And then that folder will be allowed for resources. You can call them as

```
< script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/js/properties.js" >
</ script>
```

Comment: I have already add this line to my dispatcher. How can I check if my js is loaded?

Comment: use browser to load urls manually. Either url will be wrong or file will not be at that path.

Comment: Use Tools-> Web Developer -> Web Console to see js errors.

Comment: I executed my program from eclipse. How can I do this from eclipse browser?

Comment: In Eclipse Change Browser to mozilla if it is installed already, In Preferences -> General -> Web Browser, there is USe Internal Web Browswer. And you can check "FireFox".

Comment: I executed my url from chrome browser and I get the message prueba not defined

Comment: It means the function is not getting or js is not fetched. Did u get message `cargado properties`?

Comment: Use `< script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/js/properties.js" />`

Comment: I don't see message  "cargado properties"